# Centos OS https shows apache2 default page

Tags: apache, server, centos

I am setting up my project on centos os, i have installed my ssl certificates and updated my ssl.conf. My project is accessible using http://test.com but when i try to access https://test.com, i can see the site is secure, but it displays the default apache in page. This is despite the fact that i have specified the directory and document root in my 443 virtualhost. Is there a step or error i have, any advise or useful links will be appreciated.

My code looks like this :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/strategy"
ServerName test.com/
ServerAlias www.test.com
<Directory "/var/www/html/strategy">
RewriteEngine on

# if (HTTP_ACCESS.contains('text/html') && file_not_exists(REQUEST_FILENAME))
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [last]

    # Any ressources loaded by index.html should behave correctly (i.e: Return 404 if missing)
    RewriteRule ^ - [last]

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin info@stratex.com
     ServerName www.test.com
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/strategy"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/strategy">
        DirectoryIndex index.html 
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /home/mydir/certificates/public-cert.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mydir/certificates/priv-key.pem
     
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i had a ssl.conf file, i removed the conf file for port 443 from the httpd.conf file and i updated the virtual host with port 443 in the ssl.conf file with these details and my app works well.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin info@stratex.com
     ServerName www.test.com
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/strategy"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/strategy">
        DirectoryIndex index.html 
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /home/mydir/certificates/public-cert.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mydir/certificates/priv-key.pem
     
</VirtualHost>
```